# How to perform a callback in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have here a function which gets a `Section`. It returns a `Promise`

```
router.get('/menu_section', (req, res) => {
    Section.read(req.body)
        .then(d => {
            send(d, res);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            error(e, res);
        });
});
```

Is there a way, that while I handle the `Promise` I can cut down on the `then` `catch` boilerplate code? I am looking to write it in this way to reduce boiler plate.

```
router.get('/menu_section', (req, res) => {
    Section.read(req.body).respond(data, err, res)
});

//handle it in this way for all routes. 
function respond(data, err, res){
  if(err) res.data({err})
  else res.json({data});
}
```

EDIT: I want to avoid writing `then` `catch` altogether for every Promise handle

Comment: It looks like you're using the [Express](https://expressjs.com) library for your routing, is that correct?

Comment: @NielsdeBruin Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do exactly what you mentioned (without overriding `Promise`, which is generally frowned upon).

You could however create a simple wrapping function to do it for you:

```
function respond(promise, res) {
  promise
    .then(data) => res.data(data))
    .catch(err => res.data({err})
}

router.get('/menu_section', (req, res) => {
  respond(Section.read(req.body), res);
});
```

You could even boil this down a bit to something like this:

```
function respond(getData) {
  return (req, res) => {
    getData(req)
    .then(data) => res.data(data))
    .catch(err => res.data({err})
  };
}

router.get('/menu_section', respond(req => Section.read(req.body)));
```

With the second approach, you're basically just providing a function which gets the data, then it'll take that and process it in a standard way. It'll also create a function for taking `req` and `res` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with currying?:

```
const respond = res => data => {
  res.json(data);
};
```

So you can do:

```
router.get('/menu_section', (req, res) => {
    Section.read(req.body).catch(e => e).then(respond(res));
});
```

---

However then i would directly make a middleware out of it:

```
const respond = (req, res, next) => {
  Section.read(req.body).then(
   data => res.json(data),
   err => next(err)
  );
};
```

So you can do

```
 router.get('/menu_section', respond);
```

---

Note that `async` / `await` can be helpful here:

```
router.get('/menu_section', async (req, res) => {
 try {
    res.json(await Section.read(req.body));
 } catch(e) {
   res.json(e);
 }
});
```

Comment: I would want to avoid writing `then` or `catch` for every function. And I want to handle it generically for all routes. So that the response of the promise would be caught by a single Promise handler in which I would define `then` or `catch`. 

Using Async/Await also introduces me to write a bit of boilerplate

EDIT : Something like  @samanime 's solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to respond to all routes in this manner, you could use a [Middleware function](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) and use it application wide.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => (
  Section.read(req.body)
    .then(d => send(d, res))
    .catch(e => error(e, res));
)
```

You can also use such function on a per-route basis, or even per-file (containing multiple routes).